# Clang with Code::Blocks on Debian Wheezy [Stable]

Tags: debian, apt, compiler

In my pretty default Debian install:

```
devsys@zotac:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)
Release:    7.4
Codename:   wheezy
```

I used `apt-get install clang` to do a default install of the Clang compiler.

```
devsys@zotac:~$ clang --version
Debian clang version 3.0-6.2 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

devsys@zotac:~$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

Then I do `apt-get install codeblocks` to do a default install of the Code::Blocks IDE.

```
devsys@zotac:~$ which codeblocks
/usr/bin/codeblocks
```

When starting up, and in its about box, Code::Blocks (CB) reports its version as `10.05`

CB did not mention clang when it started up and there is nothing in the CB log about clang.

In the *Compiler and Debugger Settings->Global Compiler Settings->Selected Compiler* I have what looks like the standard CB compiler selections (and these are also the only ones I can see when I create a new project):

- GNU GCC Compiler
- Intel C/C++ Compiler
- SDCC Compiler Tiny C Compiler
- GDC D Compiler
- Digital Mars D Compiler
- GNU ARM GCC Compiler
- GNU AVR GCC Compiler
- GNU GCC Compiler for Power PC
- GNU GCC Compiler for TriCore

Under *Compiler and Debugger Settings->Global Compiler Settings->Toolchain executables->Program Files->C Compiler*, when I open up the file browser I can scroll up and see `clang` and `clang++` under `/usr/bin`.  So theoretically I can create a profile for clang, but my understanding is that CB should be able to do this for me.So:

1. Is there a way to get Code::Blocks to pick up on my Clang install?
2. If there is no automatic way, what is the proper way to manually tell Code::Blocks about Clang?
3. How should I have done the installation?

Comment: Can you say more about what `Code::Blocks` is? Is this a library? Is it packaged for Debian? If so, what is the name of the package? If not, how did you install it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha See edits

Comment: Which version of Debian is this, please? Wheezy, testing/jessie, unstable?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in my slightly non-standard setup of Debian wheezy, with a self backport of clang 3.4 and codeblocks from wheezy backports. You might be better off asking on a support forum for codeblocks.

Comment: Also, if you do figure it out, it is a good idea to post your answer here. Self-answering is encouraged.

Comment: @FaheemMitha So in your setup, codeblocks detected clang and performed the appropriate setup actions?

Comment: When I started it up, it just said that it detected clang. I didn't take it any further. What compilers did yours detect?

Comment: @FaheemMitha See my edits.  CB never reported seeing clang at all

Comment: You mention a CB log. Where is that?

Comment: @FaheemMitha CB = Code::Blocks

Comment: You misunderstand. You wrote "there is nothing in the CB log about clang." What is contained in this log, and where on the filesystem is it located?

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution would be to update `Code::Blocks` to the latest version. In `Code::Blocks 13.12`  `clang` is listed as one of the supported compilers.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the project I was working on died, so I haven't had to touch that system in months :-(